# Why can't we import/export treeview and xml

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

I'm not sure if this question can be asked here but it's been bugging me for so long I have to try and get a good answer.

There are methods, properties and events for the most common usage of controls. If it does not exist as a class method,there is usually a good reson for it and it is do-able with a work around (most of the time).

Can someone explain why there is no way to simply take a `XmlDocument` and build a `Treeview` from it by simply calling a method ? Same goes for the opposite. Why can't we simply export/save a `TreeView` in an `XmlDocument` with the simple call of a method ?

Something like :

```
//Load
treeView.BuildFromXml(xmlDocument, xmlRootNode);

//Save
treeView.ExportToXml(xmlDocument);
```

The `TreeView` and `Xml` use the exact same structure so we use them all the times together. But everytime we have to re-do those recusrsive methods scrolling through child and parent nodes.

Is there a logical explanation for this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to "re-do those recursive methods" then either you need to make one Utilities class of your own or Extensions to 'write once, use often'.  If you do in fact have to rewrite for different functionality each time then you've answered your own question - there isn't a good generic means to do this that satisfies everyone.

Comment: Thanks well I tought about this and with the number of possible overloads I think it could be a good method.. I though about making myself a new treeview so I woudn't have to rewrite it all over again but I just wanted to know if there was a logical explanation to all of this.